# Wicket: There is no application attached to the current thread

Tags: multithreading, wicket

I want to login from a Desktop application to a wicket webpage. Because of this I want to check periodically that some specific parameters are present.

But when I run my code the following exception is thrown.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-13" org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: There is no application attached to current thread Thread-13
```

This is my code:

```
public class SignIn extends WebPage {
public SignIn()
{

    // Create feedback panel and add to page
    add(new FeedbackPanel("feedback"));

    // Add sign-in form to page
    add(new SignInForm("signInForm"));
    startLoginChecker(new LoginRunnable());

}

/**
 * Sign in form
 */
public final class SignInForm extends Form<Void>
{
    private static final String USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    // El-cheapo model for form
    private final ValueMap properties = new ValueMap();

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param id
     *            id of the form component
     */
    public SignInForm(final String id)
    {
        super(id);

        // Attach textfield components that edit properties map model
        add(new TextField<String>(USERNAME, new PropertyModel<String>(properties, USERNAME)));
        add(new PasswordTextField(PASSWORD, new PropertyModel<String>(properties, PASSWORD)));
    }

    /**
     * @see org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form#onSubmit()
     */
    @Override
    public final void onSubmit()
    {
        // Get session info
        SignInSession session = getMySession();

        // Sign the user in
        if (session.signIn(getUsername(), getPassword()))
        {

                setResponsePage(getApplication().getHomePage());

        }
        else
        {
            // Get the error message from the properties file associated with the Component
            String errmsg = getString("loginError", null, "Unable to sign you in");

            // Register the error message with the feedback panel
            error(errmsg);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    private String getPassword()
    {
        return properties.getString(PASSWORD);
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    private String getUsername()
    {
        return properties.getString(USERNAME);
    }

    /**
     * @return
     */
    private SignInSession getMySession()
    {
        return (SignInSession)getSession();
    }
}

public void startLoginChecker(Runnable runnable) {
    Thread loginThread = new Thread(runnable);
    loginThread.start();
}

private class LoginRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int checkLoginPeriod = 1000; //1sec in milliseconds
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(checkLoginPeriod);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final SignInSession session = (SignInSession)getSession();

        while(!session.isSignedIn()) {
            if (session.signIn("wicket", "wicket"))

            {

                setResponsePage(getApplication().getHomePage());

            } else

            {
                // Get the error message from the properties file associated with the Component
                String errmsg = getString("loginError", null, "Unable to sign you in");

                // Register the error message with the feedback panel
                error(errmsg);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

}

How can I avoid this problem and check periodically from a thread multiple parameters.

Gracias in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want this Thread.. What will it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should just use a `AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior` to implement your desired functionlality. In this case (because you are moving to another page), I think it is more appropriate to use its superclass: `AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior`

Just add this to your Page / Panel

```
  add(new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.seconds(1)){

      protected void onTimer(AjaxRequestTarget target)
      {
          // Get session info
          SignInSession session = getMySession();              
          // Sign the user in
          if (session.signIn(getUsername(), getPassword()))
          {
              setResponsePage(getApplication().getHomePage());
          }
      }
  });
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for this hint, but it seems that the method onTimer is final and can't be overwritten?

Answer (score 1):

I think so:

take (Application application) in page to thread pool, at pool add if:

```
if (!Application.exists()) {
    ThreadContext.setApplication(application);
}
```